# Bind Path in ResourceDictionary's dependant on VM property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, resourcedictionary

I've created a ResourceDictionary that defines a bunch of `System.Windows.Shapes.Path` that are used in the ContentPresenter of a Button ControlTemplate.

I'd like to change one of the Paths out based on a ViewModel property. If `true` the button uses one path from the ResourceDictionary, if `false` a different one.

Currently I just reference a StaticResource in the xaml to point directly to the path I want displayed.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to modify the content template of the button in style by referring to the elements from you resource dictionary.

Something like this: 
`<Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource cp2}"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource cp1}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>`

I have used mouse over property as my trigger to change the content template.
You can use `DataTrigger` instead of `Trigger`